# Why can't you use shorthand array initialization of fields in Java constructors?

Tags: java, arrays, array-initialization

Take the following example:

```
private int[] list;

public Listing() {
    // Why can't I do this?
    list = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    // I have to do this:
    int[] contents = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    list = contents;
}
```

Why can't I use shorthand initialization? The only way I can think of getting around this is making another array and setting `list` to that array.

Comment: Your last sentence appears to be uncompleted. Making *what*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: array initialization syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387643/java-array-initialization-syntax)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you define the array on the definition line, it assumes it know what the type will be so the `new int[]` is redundant.  However when you use assignment it doesn't assume it know the type of the array so you have specify it.

Certainly other languages don't have a problem with this, but in Java the difference is whether you are defining and initialising the fields/variable on the same line.

Comment: So is `int[]` a value- or a reference-type?

Comment: `int[]` is a class. You can get the Class instance with `Class intArrayClass = int[].class;`

Comment: That's what I was looking for. This question came about in my AP CS class, and my teacher didn't know either. I just wanted a less hacky way of declaring the contents of an array besides creating another one.

Answer (score 23):

Try `list = new int[]{4, 5, 6, 7, 8};`.

Comment: You're not really answering the concrete question. OP clearly asked why he can't use *shorthand* initialization, so we may assume that he's well aware that full initialization works.

Comment: BalusC - good catch - though it is shorthand (at least compared to his work-around) - just not as short-hand as he was probably hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using `new Object[]{blah, blah....}` Here is a slightly shorter approach to do what you want. Use the method below.

```
public static Object [] args(Object... vararg) {
    Object[] array = new Object[vararg.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < vararg.length; i++) {
        array[i] = vararg[i];
    }
    return array;
}
```

PS - Java is good, but it sucks in situations like these. Try ruby or python for your project if possible & justifiable. (Look [java 8 still has no shorthand for populating a hashmap](http://minborgsjavapot.blogspot.com/2014/12/java-8-initializing-maps-in-smartest-way.html), and [it took them so long to make a small change to improve developer productivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialise-a-static-map))