# why is the array giving an error?

Tags: java

why is here: **arrayList = {firstName, lastName, ID, examValue, score};** gives an error?? The method should call a constructor which is Exam(String firstName, String lastName, int ID, String examType, int score), so what's is wrong with this method? Thanks in advance!

```
public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s)
    {
        Exam[] arrayList = null;
        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        int ID = 0;
        String examValue = "";
        int score = 0;

        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            if(s.hasNextLine())
            {
                firstName = s.next();
                lastName = s.next();
            }
            else if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                ID = s.nextInt();
            }
            else if (s.hasNextLine())
            {
                examValue = s.nextLine();
            }
            else if (s.hasNextInt())
            {
                score = s.nextInt();
            }

        }

        arrayList = {firstName, lastName, ID, examValue, score};
        return arrayList;


    }
```

Comment: You can't initialize an array that way after the declaration. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387643/array-initialization-syntax-when-not-in-a-declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot initialize an array as `Exam[] arrayList = null;` and then reassign the value to an array of length 5.

Secondly, your `ArrayList` is a List of different objects and primitives (`String`, `int`), and does not match the specified type `Exam[]`.

Either change the type of objects assigned to the `Exam` list, or make sure all of the objects in the list are of type `Exam`.

Comment: how can all of the objects be of type Exam? Could please provide any examples of all of the objects of type Exam? @rageandqq

Comment: You would have to make sure all of the objects in the list (`firstName, lastName, ID, examValue, score`)  are of type Exam and not what they currently are (string, int, etc). That, or change `arrayList` to accept different types (have it just as an ArrayList` type and not an array of `Exam` objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `arrayList = new Exam[]{ /* stuff */ }`. The syntaxis you tried to use is valid only in an array declaration.

Also, you can't initialize an array of type `Exam` with variables of different basic types.

Comment: I'm new to objects, Could you please provide any examples using objects in an array @Mints97 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here `Exam[] arrayList = null;` you say array is of type Exam then you say
`arrayList = {firstName, lastName, ID, examValue, score};`  array is of type String  that 2 statements contradict each other