# Double brace initializer and array

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, constructor, initializer

I have a method having an array parameter like:

```
public static void foo(int[] param) {
    // Some code
}
```

And also I can call the method by writing like

```
foo(new int[3]);
```

Normally, we declare and initialize an array by new operator or double braces initializer like {1, 2, 3}. For example, `int[] foo = new int[3];` **or** `int[] foo = {1, 2, 3};`.

But it's impossible to use double brace initializer as a parameter for a method. `{}` is only available for creating an array object.

And here is my question: Are there any differences between new operator and `{}`? 
If there is, what is it?

Comment: thanks for your comment, Scary. and that's exactly my point. foo ({1, 2, 3}) is not working...

Comment: `foo (new int[] {1, 2, 3})` works

Comment: @Eran yes, but the question here is why does int[] i = {1,2,3}; work but not foo({1,2,3});

Comment: Does int[] foo = {1, 2, 3} really work? I had no idea. Just when you thought you knew all the syntax of the java language.. ;)

Comment: may be... double braces VS `new` is int x[] = new int[10] you are allocating 10 locations (only length, no values) , they contain init-value based on type (primetive types) or NULL for objects, however, `{1,4,7}` will init values + length or `{}` will mean new array with `length=0`

Comment: maybe because {1,2,3} is not an array but just the initialization values for an array?

Comment: thanks Eran. certainly foo (new int[] {1, 2, 3}) works but foo ({1, 2, 3}). my point is there is some way to create an array like new int[3], new int[] {1,2,3}, and {1,2,3} using new operator or {}. but when we call a method, we can only use new operator. not {}. i guess there is some kind of differences between new operator and {}, and want to know that.

Comment: Note: What you show here is **not** what is known as [double brace initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java). Use the correct terminology to avoid confusion.

Comment: Check out the "Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array" section of this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Foo({3,4,5}) really doesnt have a datatype defined. That would work in python but in java you require a datatype

Comment: By the way, you're using the term double braces initialization wrong. This is what you would call it: new ArrayList(){{add(1);}} Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java

Comment: You might want to use var-args instead of an array parameter: `void foo(int...params)` and call with `foo(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `{}` as part of a `int foo[] = {1, 2, 3};` is what is termed as brace initialization, and is a shortcut for `int foo[] = new int[]{1, 2, 3};` because the `new int[]` can be inferred from the left hand side.

In the second case `foo({1, 2, 3});` no inference of what you intend can be determined as there is no hint as to what the `{1, 2, 3}` means, so the compiler complains.

When you rewrite it as `foo(new int[]{1, 2, 3});` you're telling the compiler what the item in `{}` is meant to represent.

The compiler won't (and does not try) to auto-interpret the `{}` expression until it matches - that would lead to potential ambiguities.

There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387643/array-initialization-syntax-when-not-in-a-declaration), which seems to cover exactly the same ground.

As mentioned by @benzonico, it is part of the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-ArrayInitializer) as to this being a supported syntax, which doesn't include it being used in the invocation of a method.

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete the other answer, you can have a look at the [JLS 8 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-ArrayInitializer): you can see that in the grammar a variable initializer is either an expression OR (exclusive) an array initializer (which is not an expression and thus cannot be use when invoking a method).