# Failed to pass array as parameter in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method `doSomething()` which accept Array as parameter. When I pass array like bellow:

```
package org.my;

public class ArrayMistry {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        doSomething({1,2});// Compilation Error
    }   

    public static void doSomething(int[] params) {

    }   

}
```

I am getting compilation error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     Syntax error on token "doSomething", @ expected before
>   this token    Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete
>   EnumHeader    Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete
>   BlockStatements
>
> at org.my.ArrayMistry.main(ArrayMistry.java:6)

Note:

if I pass as bellow then its OK:

```
public static void main(String ... args) {
    int[] p = {1,2};
    doSomething(p);// no Error
    doSomething(new int[]{1,2});// no Error
}
```

Comment: Read this post which explains the problem more in-depth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387643/array-initialization-syntax-when-not-in-a-declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are passed by reference. You need to create an array object with [1,2] and pass the reference of that created object to `dosomething`. The `new` keyword allocates space for the creation of this `int` array.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1,2};
doSomething(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you aren't declaring {1, 2} as a new array. It must be declared as `new int[]{1,2}` to function properly, otherwise you are not creating an array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an array to pass into a method because you initialized the method that way. The reason this `doSomething({1,2});` doesn't work is because the array has not been initialized and {1, 2} is not an array, it is just some numbers in a parenthesis. if you wanted to send an array you have to do something like this

```
int[] p = {1,2};
doSomething(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method doSomething() specifically accepts an array of integers as its parameters.

Note in both cases where it worked, you either passed an existing array, or created a new one when passing it in.

In your original example, you are passing an arbitrary set of numbers with no memory reserved, or type specified.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem is by passing a reference as a parameter to the function like this:

```
doSomething(new int[]{1,2});
```