# Looping into 2d Object array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Object [][] data = new Object[4][4] ;

```
        for (int i =0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            data[i]={"a","b","c","d"};
        }
```

is there any way to fill the 2 day array with a way similar to that, 
NOTE: a ,b,c and d are different data so i can't use 2 loops to fill the array i 'm searching to a close way to that

when i tried to do

```
            data[i]={"a","b","c","d"};
```

i thought it was going to work but for a reason it didn't

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5387643/6245535

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "new" or give the indexes

Something like this:

```
data[i]= new Object[]{"a","b","c","d"};
```

or

```
data[i][0] = "a";
data[i][1] = "b";
data[i][2] = "c";
data[i][3] = "d";
```