# Is it necessary to explicitly instantiate an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object

How does instantiation work in this code:

```
// decleration
dataType[] arrayRefVar;

//instantiation - is it required?
arrayRefVar = new dataType[arraySize];   //A

arrayRefVar[0]=1;  //B
arrayRefVar[1]=2;
```

I am from a C++ background, so i don't really understand creation of objects/arrays with 'new'. I know it is for allocating memory to the array and returning reference. Will the creation of array take place automatically at B if line A is skipped?

**Edit:** Found a similar one, if anyone interested:
[Array initialization syntax when not in a declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387643/array-initialization-syntax-when-not-in-a-declaration)

Comment: Find out for yourself: what happens if you omit that line?

Comment: `int arr[];` means what in c++?

Comment: @AndyTurner , i got this 
error: variable arrayRefVar might not have been initialized, so i guess not

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Deceleration, i would say, i am only familier with deceleration and and initialisation, creating/instantiation stuff is wierd for me

Comment: have you tried to do as mentioned in the answers and comments?

Comment: You can't do this in C++ either...

Comment: I was referring to the empty array initialization, e.g. `dataType[] arrayRefVar;`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider me too, sorry, i meant both declaration and instantiation combined into one step in C++ called 'declaration', `int arrayName[20]; //declaration in C++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just reference(pointer) declaration  but not object creation

```
// decleration
dataType[] arrayRefVar;
```

**new** keyword specifies that new memory location for given Type has to be created. This step is your actual object creation not the above step.You are pointing the reference named  **arrayRefVar**  to the newely created object.

```
//instantiation -
arrayRefVar = new dataType[arraySize];   //A
```

Without step 2, you will get NullPointerException.Meaning your trying to assign value to an object which does not exist

Answer (score 0):

It will not.
when you create an array, the java virtual machine allocated the needed space.

The compiler does this because of the keyword `new`.

```
dataType[] arrayRefVar;



arrayRefVar[0]=1;  //B
arrayRefVar[1]=2;
```

essentially, this code would try to access a data address (`arrayRefVar[0]`) that is used for something else/not used.

initializing the array allocates those addresses.